# Using Kubernetes ingress with two services and internal web API routing

Tags: c#, nginx, kubernetes, asp.net-web-api, nginx-ingress

I have two ASP.NET Core applications app1 and app2. Inside these apps I have routes as defined in this simplified code:

app1:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/app1ep1", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("x1");
});

endpoints.MapGet("/app1ep2", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("x2");
});
```

app2:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/app2ep1", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("y1");
});

endpoints.MapGet("/app2ep2", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("y2");
});
```

I am trying to define without success an ingress rule that will apply the following routings:

- myhost.com/app1/app1ep1 will route to the service app1 and then internal routing to ep1
- myhost.com/app2/app2ep1 will route to the service app2 and then internal routing to ep1
- the point goes on, please comment if extra clarification required

My ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /app2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice2
            port:
              number: 80
```

Actual result is that the services are found but I get 404 error. In other words, browsing to myhost.com/app1/app1ep1 (or any other combination) routes to the service (myservice1) but then internal route is lost.
Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks for helping

Edit:
I am noticing some other problem. I tried to reduce the problem to a single service. So my ingress now looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice1
            port:
              number: 80
```

Also added this controller to the "myservice1" app:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("x");
});
```

Going to myhost.com/app1 returns 404. That again means that the app is found but the route isn't found in the application (although I defined "/" route).
Maybe this information can help discover the problem

Comment: From inside the container (or from a node of the cluster, using the IP address assigned to one of the containers where such apps are running) if you curl at the right address, you obtain the right response or 404 like with the ingress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue with the following ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /app2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice2
            port:
              number: 80
```